Put a chat command under feature toggle defined in extension settings in a vscode extension
I am trying to put a chat command under a feature toggle controlled by the extension settings. The toggle is not working as expected at the time of initial run. Only once I toggle the feature off/on again does it start to work as expected. I have kept the feature toggle to be true by default but the command does not appear in the chat commands. Only once I turn it off/on again does it start reflecting the state correctly.
Here is what I have tried:
File: package.json
"contributes": {
"chatParticipants": [
  {
      {
        "name": "featureUnderToggle",
        "description": "Test feature",
        "when": "feature.enableFeature == true"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"configuration": {
  "title": "VS Code Extension",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "feature.enableFeature": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true,
      "description": "Enable feature",
      "order": 0
    }
  }
}}]

In the extension.ts activate function:
vscode.workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration((event: vscode.ConfigurationChangeEvent) => {
    if(event.affectsConfiguration('feature.enableFeature')) {
        const isFeatureEnabled = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('feature').get('enableFeature') || false;
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'feature.enableFeature', isFeatureEnabled);
    }

I need help getting this to work correctly. How can I fix this?
